# $\mathcal{f}$(A $\cap$ B) = $\mathcal{f}$(A) $\cap$ $\mathcal{f}$(B) $\iff$ $\mathcal{f}$ is injective. Numerical example and counterexample.

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples

Need some help to check whether my understanding of a subject is right or not.

$1$. Example of injective function.

$\mathcal{f}$: $\mathbb{N}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{N}$

$x$ $\longmapsto$ $2x$

A = {$1,2,3,4$}, B = {$2,4,5,7$}, (A $\cap$ B) = {$2,4$}

$\mathcal{f}$(A) = {$2,4,6,8$}, $\space$ $\mathcal{f}$(B) = {$4,8,10,14$}

$\mathcal{f}$(A $\cap$ B) =  $\mathcal{f}$(A) $\cap$ $\mathcal{f}$(B) = {$4,8$} $\Longrightarrow$ $\mathcal{f}$ is injective

$2$. Example of a function that is not injective

$\mathcal{f}$: $\mathbb{R}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$

$x$ $\longmapsto$ $x^2$

A = {$2,4,6,8$}, B = {$-4,-8,-12,-16$}, (A $\cap$ B) = $\lbrace$ $\emptyset$ $\rbrace$

$\mathcal{f}$(A) = {$4,16,36,64$}, $\space$ $\mathcal{f}$(B) = {$16,64,144,256$}

$\mathcal{f}$(A) $\cap$ $\mathcal{f}$(B) = {$16,64$} $\neq$ $\mathcal{f}$(A $\cap$ B) = $\lbrace$ $\emptyset$ $\rbrace$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\mathcal{f}$ is not injective

Are there any mistakes in these writings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a mistake, and a big one: you cannot fix two sets $A$ and $B$ and claim that$$f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)\implies\ f\text{ injective.}$$That equality holds for those two specific set, but that fact, by itslef, is not enough to assure that $f$ is injective.

The rest looks correct.

Comment: however, if it holds for all subsets, or at least the singleton subsets, it should work out.

Comment: @Enkidu Indeed, but the OP only claimed that it holds for two specific sets.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, if the statement (from the title of the post) holds for all subsets of the domain of a function then we can say that this function is injective. While we only need at least two arbitrarily subsets of the domain for which the statement doesn't hold to state that the function is not injective. Right?

Comment: Completely right!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another mistake: If $A = \{2,4,6,8\}, B = \{-4,-8,-12,-16\}$ then $A \cap B \ne \{ \emptyset \}$.

$A \cap B = \emptyset$

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. You are saying that there is a mistake in the following line "If A={2,4,6,8}, B={−4,−8,−12,−16} then A∩B ≠ {∅}". However, in my post I write that A∩B = ∅.

Comment: No, in your post you wrote $A \cap B = \{\emptyset\}$. Be careful: $\{\emptyset\} \ne \emptyset$

Comment: I see. Thank you!